# Using Sonos API even though server is not on the same internet - Sonos SOCO & WayScript

Tags: sonos

I have made a script that uses the library [SOCO](https://github.com/SoCo/SoCo), to play songs on my Sonos. I have deployed this script at WayScript. The issue is that WayScript runs it's scripts on it's own server, which isn't connected to my internet.

Therefore, when I try to connect to my Sonos device: SoCo('192.168.1.10'), it can't connect... obviously.

So what do I do? Maybe Sonos provides another way to interact with their devices, even though the server is not connected to the same Wi-Fi.

Thanks in advance,
Villads

Answer (score 0):

Use the Sonos Cloud API, which does not require access to your local Wifi network. https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/